# Usefulness of univariate time series methods

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, garch

When are time series techniques (such as ARIMA and GARCH for exams) more useful in forecasting than simple eyeballing in the univariate case? I find that often eyeballing can give better point estimates than ARIMA sometimes.

So what is the point of the models? Is it to be able to incorporate the forecast intervals? Can their point estimates be better  simply looking at the trend and extrapolating?

Comment: If you can eyeball the point forecast better, why couldn't you also eyeball a forecast interval (these are called forecast intervals, not confidence intervals; the latter are for estimates rather than forecasts)?

Comment: This is an intriguing claim.  I, for one, would be interested in seeing the evidence you have used to conclude that "eyeballing can give better point estimates ... sometimes."  What exactly is "eyeballing," who would be doing it, on what kinds of data, for what duration of forecasts, and how would they be supplying error estimates or prediction intervals?

Comment: Hi guys. I'll make the edit (changing confidence interval to forecast interval), thank you. I do concede that the models are more useful when it comes to providing forecast intervals. However, what I was hoping for was an example where one could not have made a reasonable point forecast without using an ARIMA model. Essentially, I'd like use cases for the performance of ARIMA on a univariate time series.

Comment: Take some collection of time series and compare your eyeballing to ARIMA forecasts. For example, the performance of some forecasting methods on M3 forecast competition data is available at Rob J. Hyndman's blog [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/show-me-the-evidence/), and the data is also publicly available (for example, in an R package). See if you can beat, say, `auto.arima`. Unless you are a truly terrific eyeballer, I suspect it will be very difficult to do.